# Why does Play 1.x doesn't cache precompiled code from previous runs?

Tags: playframework

I'm running Play in prod mode, and on startup it precompiles all the code, which takes about a minute. What I don't understand is why this happens every time play starts, even if no code has changed.

Doesn't it use a cache folder for the compiled sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First precompile your application with `play precompile`, then start it with `play start -Dprecompiled=true`.

Please note that in Play 1.x you still need the templates code in /app, see [How can I deploy Play! framework application standalone (no war) and not include the source in app folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847587/how-can-i-deploy-play-framework-application-standalone-no-war-and-not-include)!

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to start with precompiled sources. I mean it is `play start --procompiled`.